# Can recalled functions with incremented class variables continue to be added?

Tags: python, function, class, increment

I have an issue with the below program in Python3 which takes in a string where the number of values in the string determine if the function continues again when recalled. I was informed that if I used an incrementable variable such as self.turn = 0 in the initializer, I would be able to use it in move() without having to define it in move() as not to have an infinite loop. The issue I have is that when I run the program and input 'good input' (>=3) more than once, the incrementable variable self.turn stays at 1 rather than increasing as I would like. Is there a way to continue the incrementation after each time the function is recalled?
Thanks,
Yuri

```html
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = 'A'
        self.turn = 0 

    def move(self, move):
        self.move = move
        if self.turn == 0 and len(move) <3:
            self.turn+=1
            print('Your current total of turns: ',self.turn)
            print()
            exit()
        
        if len(move) >= 3 :
            print('good input')
            self.turn +=1
            print('Your current total of turns: ',self.turn)
            print()
        
        else:
            print('bad input')
            self.turn +=1
            print('Your current total of turns: ',self.turn)
            print()
            exit()

        move = input('Input a move: ')
        Player().move(move)



move = input('Input a move: ')
Player().move(move)
```

Comment: `Player().move(move)` makes a *new* player and moves it.

Comment: `turn` is properly called an attribute, not a class variable. A class variable is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so 2 things that make your code not run properly:

1. The last line of code from `move` method is creating new objects of `Player` class instead of calling the same object. To call the method from the same object from inside the method, you should use `self` keyword instead.
2. You shouldn't name your a method with the same name as a variable, because their definition will colide. I've changed to `add_move` instead.

Also, your first if statement is not necessary, since the condition is already verified in the next `if` and the `else` contains basically the same code, so I'm removing this part.

With that said, this code should now work:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = 'A'
        self.turn = 0

    def add_move(self, move):
        self.move = move

        if len(move) >= 3:
            print('good input')
            self.turn += 1
            print('Your current total of turns: ', self.turn)
            print()

        else:
            print('bad input')
            self.turn += 1
            print('Your current total of turns: ', self.turn)
            print()
            exit()

        move = input('Input a move: ')
        self.add_move(move)  # Now it won't create new objects. Neither colide.


move = input('Input a move: ')
Player().add_move(move)
```